# How to enable forms authentication programmatically?

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication

So, my attempts are:
1)`Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[currentZone].AuthenticationMode = System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationMode.Forms;`                                                        `Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[currentZone].MembershipProvider = "MyMembershipProvider";`
`Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[currentZone].EnableClientIntegration = true;`                                                       `Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[currentZone].AllowAnonymous = false;`                                                 `Site.WebApplication.Update();`
2) Change web.config (authentication, impersonation, login page url).
But then I cannot authenticate any user. Please help!
Response of the request to /_vti_bin/authentication.asmx is 401 Unauthorized. And IIS settings are strange - 
[image: IIS settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved. It was necessary to install all updates for operation system.